# Логика взаимодействия окон и контекста MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm

Допустим у меня есть унифицированное окошко. `BasicDialogUI`. Там у меня кнопочки и прочие. И есть `BasicDialogViewModel`, и у него куча детей, разные окна у которых есть одно общее - входе взаимодействия юзера с окном, юзер получает какой либо результат. Теперь необходимо придумать как связать ViewModel и окошко.

Есть идея описать событие в `BasicDialogViewModel` - `GetResult`, и в окне `BasicDialogUI` хранить объект `object Result`. И там где я вызываю это окошко, обрабатывать это событие, ибо по правилам MVVM, UI не должен быть привязан к контексту - ViewModel.

Интересуют варианты решений, унифицированные.

Comment: А не ставите ли вы телегу впереди лошади? Событие у вас должно быть у `BasicDialogUI`, а обработчик события в `BasicDialogViewModel`. Или есть "главная" вьюмодель, она запускает `BasicDialogUI` и `BasicDialogViewModel` и подписана на события в `BasicDialogViewModel`, которая в свою очередь транслирует события ввода данных из  `BasicDialogUI`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте решить с помощью DependencyProperty своего BasicDialogUI

```
public int Document_Type_ID
    {
        get
        {
             return (int)GetValue(Document_Type_ID_Property);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(Document_Type_ID_Property, value);
        }
    }

public static readonly DependencyProperty Document_Type_ID_Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Document_Type_ID", typeof(int), typeof(View.BasicDialogUI), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```